# Am I wrong or this is right about pre-increment(++) operator

Tags: c, pre-increment

ok if I type "++n" in c then the value of n is incremented by one but when i type this code the output is not as i expected

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int n = 2;
    printf("%d %d\n", ++n, n*n);
    }
```

and then the output is 3 4 but when i ask this to chatGPT it shows the output is 3 9 even i asked it that "VS Code shows 3 4 and how " it says it might be issue with iDLe
[When i ask to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRWpX.png)
[When i ask about the output i got in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfCVe.png)

When i type this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int n = 2;
    printf("%d %d\n", ++n, n*n);
    }
```

i was expected to get "3 9" but i got "3 4" how

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't know everything. In fact it doesn't 'know' anything. What it doesn't know here is that you are in the land of undefined behaviour (UB). Here `n*n` was evaluated before `++n`.

Comment: so, the ++n does its job and does not affect the n*n
but ChatGPT is not smart enough to figure that out.
thx man

Comment: @whited No, the code as written has no defined outcome because it's a bug. Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including results that might _seem_ correct or deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

You cant access n in the same statement after ++

clangs warning:

```
main.c:4:21: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'n' [-Wunsequenced]
  printf("%d %d\n", ++n, n * n);
                    ^    ~
```

Answer (score -2):

The current value of n is used consistently in the statement - i.e. it takes the value 2 for n in all three places and then it operates on it. For the first mention of n it increases its value by 1 and then uses the resulting value, but it has already (kind of in parallel) used the value of 2 for the second and third mentions of n.

Don't trust ChatGPT.

Comment: The order of evaluation of the parameters in a function call is not defined in the standard. You should correct this answer before the DV's begin...

Comment: Any answer which doesn't mention sequencing, order of evaluation or undefined behavior is just as wrong as ChatGPT.

Comment: Both this answer and the other downvoted answer actually answer OPs question. The question was about actual implemented behaviour, not the C standard. In OP's case VSC implements it the way both I and the other poster have explained.